# How to remove a response header in nginx after having stored its value in case of proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

Fundamentally, I am having troubles to find out a way to remove a response header in nginx in case of proxy_pass after having stored it in a variable.
proxy_hide_header doesn't let me store the value.

In other words:

I am trying to get access to a custom response header, save it into a variable, and get rid of it so that it will not be propagated to the client. That variable is then used in the access logs. 
Unfortunately, the following doesn't seem to work:

```
http {

log_format main '$remote_addr $http_host $destination_addr [$time_local]   
"$request" $status';
access_log /opt/logs/access.log main;

server { 
 listen 142.133.151.129:8090 default; 

 ##This is my internal variable for the response header field 
 set $destination_addr "-"; 

 location / { 
   proxy_pass http://my_upstream_server; 

   #store the response header field
   set $destination_addr $sent_http_x_destination; 

   #now get rid of this response header field
   set $sent_http_x_destination ""; 
  }   
 }
}
```

I am getting empty values for $sent_http_x_destination.

Here is the curl request and response:

```
# curl -Ov http://142.133.151.129:8090/ao3/vod/soccer/worldcup2014/final1

< HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
< Server: openresty/1.9.3.1
< Date: Tue, 16 Feb 2016 22:25:32 GMT
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Content-Length: 99990100
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Destination: 142.133.151.94
```

Does anyone know how to remove "X-Destination" after having it stored and used for access log? I am getting "$destination_addr" with empty value.

Thanks

Comment: I used `proxy_hide_header my-custome-header;` and worked as expected. It removes the header from the response, but the variable `$upstream_http_my_custom_header` is written in the log.

Answer (score 11):

one could use `proxy_hide_header` to remove header returned to NGINX from the proxy, see [ngx_http_proxy_module docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_hide_header)
`$upstream_http_x_destination` can be used for logging, see [ngx_http_upstream_module docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html)

rewrite of your config would look like this:

```
http {
  log_format main '$remote_addr $http_host $upstream_http_x_destination '
                  '[$time_local] "$request" $status';
  access_log /opt/logs/access.log main;
  server { 
    listen 142.133.151.129:8090 default; 
    location / {
      proxy_hide_header x_destination;
      proxy_pass http://my_upstream_server; 
    }   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not completely sure about this, but I think that as long as you rely on that header for the logs, it needs to be set as a header... else, the logs won't be able to use it.

Having said that, you can try [`proxy_hide_header`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_hide_header) and see if it works.

Comment: I have already tried proxy_hide_header. It doesn't allow me to use the value of the header field in access logs. The header disappears right away. This is why I posted my question:
"In a proxy_pass server, how can we use a response header in access logs and removes it afterwards"

Comment: Like I said, if you're planning to use it on logs, you cannot make it disappear. Logs depend on those headers and those header "were already sent" to the user when they are written on the logs.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can see is to create a lua script that will re-implement the proxy pass using http-resty, saves the header in an nginx variable and removes it right before returning. The saved nginx variable will then be used for access logs.
This is my answer.
I was hoping that nginx offers a simpler way to do that.

Please let me know your comments on this answer.
Thanks for all your inputs on this topic!